# SQL Server: how can I promote headers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016

I have a table in SQL Server 2016 which looks similar to this (all columns are `nvarchar` and there are over 15 columns, also I have an `IDENTITY` column not shown):

**Table1**:

```
  [Col1]                  [Col2]                  [Col3]                  [Col4]
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------              
  12-05-2016 10:29:48     12-06-2016 03:29:48     NULL                    132.43
  StartTime               TaskNumber              EndTime                 TotalValue
  12-01-2017 11:15:00     48                      12-01-2017 12:32:00     24.1
```

As you can see, each column contains text which is actually supposed to be the column's header. How can I set the columns name equal to this value?

Note, the columns are not always in the same order. The data comes from a source that can contain the columns in any random order.

Comment: What kind of design is it? Are you storing reports in general table?

Comment: not sure if there is any new feature in 2016 like this, but you have multiple approach to do this, such as create a new table with 15 columns, insert everything with `identity insert` set to `ON`, then delete the header row...

Comment: You use a "CREATE TABLE" statement to do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql  How you write that statement is up to you. Then once it's created you'll use an INSERT.. SELECT statement to add the records from your existing table to your new table https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql

Comment: @lad2025 yes, I have a .NET function that reads an excel table and puts it into a general SQL table. It includes the headers from the Excel table, but it adds the rows in random order. Once I have the data in the DB, I merge it into another table, but I need the header names to do that

Comment: Also, I should have mentioned that the columns can be in any order, they are not always in the same order

Comment: @LONG, I supposed I could do that... I'm just not sure how I would select the headers/column names in the CREATE statement in order to label the new columns....